# Flash CS4 randomly won't open .fla file

Tags: flash, flash-cs4

All I get is an error box saying: "Unexpected file format."

Everything was going fine until I did some simple action (removing a few frames I believe), then Flash crashed and I haven't been able to reopen the file since. It opens other .flas just fine. I rebooted, but to no avail.

Any ideas? This is an important project and very frustrating. Thanks.

Comment: If the file is corrupted, you still may be able to decompile your last swf...

Comment: The .fla file is on svn and and almost all the code is in external as files, so thankfully I'm not in danger of losing too much, but I have done a couple days of graphics work since I last committed the .fla. I'm guessing that a decompiler can't really get at graphic assets?

Comment: happy to see you found out it could! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time I have ever seen the dreaded "Unexpected file format" crapola is when I try to open an FLA saved in a newer version of Flash.  If you don't have cs-5 installed, and no one else touched the file then you may be SOL.  Perhaps you can recover a lot of what you need with a decompiler.

Comment: .swf -> .fla compiler did the trick and allowed me to recover graphics. Thanks.

http://www.swf-to-fla.com/?gclid=CMaBxbudwqMCFRE95Qod-WXscQ